# The installation on the client computer is required?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a software that accesses a SQL database in the cloud. The SQL installation must be done on the client pc or my program already can access it regardless?

Comment: nope i don't think so

Comment: If you're connecting directly to a database in the cloud, you're going to need SQL access drivers but you don't need the actual database software.

Comment: If you are using the .NET Provider for SQL Server (SqlCient), all of the data access components are included with the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client only needs OLE DB Provider or an ODBC driver.  Since your using SQL Sever, you can use the SQL Sever Native Client.  More information and downloads can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff658533.aspx).

Comment: Just want to add that the OLE DB and ODBC SQL Server data access components that are provided with Windows are deprecated and should not be used for new development.  If it's a .NET app, SqlClient should be used instead.  SQL Server Native Client is also deprecated.  Microsoft recommends the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, which is a separate install.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't install SQL Server or other large RDBMS on the client. Usually this is accessed via Intranet (or less frequently over internet).

You will need to tell us more details.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about SQL drivers rather than the database engine